# How to calculate class activation map in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I understand the definition of class activation map and how to generate it in Numpy.
However, I am not sure how to calculate it in TensorFlow, especially when the batch_size dimension is unknown.

Current, I have obtained the activation of my last convolution layer "activation".
And the weight matrix for the last fully connected layer after GAP is "last_fc_w".

I wanted to calculate class activation map like this:

```
cam = tf.matmul(activation, last_fc_w)
```

However, I got the following error:
*** ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 4 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,10,10,576], [576,2].

The shape of activation tensor is [?,10,10,576], where ? is the batch_size dimension.
The shape of fully connect layer weight is [576, 2], where 2 is the number of classes, 576 is the number of channels of the last convolution layer.

The expected output will be a tensor of size [?, 10,10,2], which is the class activation map for these 2 classes. Could anyone provide some guidance on how to achieve that?

Comment: Which TF version are you trying?

Comment: @thushv89  I am currently using 1.13.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `keras.backend.dot`

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
x = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 32, 32, 3], dtype=tf.float32)
out = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(576, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
w = tf.Variable(tf.glorot_normal_initializer()([576, 2]))
print(out.shape)
cam = tf.keras.backend.dot(out, w)
print(cam.shape)
```

But in higher TF versions (tested for 1.15.0) your existing code will work. I tested the following code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
x = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 32, 32, 3], dtype=tf.float32)
out = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(576, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
w = tf.Variable(tf.glorot_normal_initializer()([576, 2]))
print(out.shape)
cam = tf.matmul(out, w)
print(cam.shape)
```

### Creating a mask from the activation map

Easy!

```
threshold = 0.5
mask = tf.cast(tf.less(cam, threshold), tf.float32) * cam
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the guidance. I finally got it to work.  Now, I have a CAM [?, 10, 10] and an activation [?, 10,10, 576], and I want to use CAM as a mask, to set activation pixels to 0 if the corresponding CAM pixels are above certain threshold value. Could you provide some guidance on how to do that in TensorFlow?